# jquery ajax code is not passing values to webservice method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My ajax code is not passing values to my webservice method .. i think i am not doning it properly. please guide me.

this is my .aspx code:

```
       $(function () {
           $.ajax({

               type: "POST",
               url: "WebService.asmx/InsertRediretTime",
               data: "{ 'ReachTime': '21-Nov-11', 'Destination': 'location' }",
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data, status) {
                   alert(data.d);
               }

           });
       });
```

and this is my webservice method

```
   public static void InsertRediretTime(string ReachTime, string Destination)
    {
    //operational code
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried removing the quote marks from the parameter names in the JSON? e.g: data: "{ ReachTime: '21-Nov-11', Destination: 'location' }",

Answer (score 3):

Take out the static keyword from your method.

```
public void InsertRediretTime(string ReachTime, string Destination)
{
//operational code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $(function () {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "WebService.asmx/InsertRediretTime",
           data: "ReachTime=21-Nov-11&Destination=location",
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data, status) {
               alert(data.d);
           }
       });
   });
```

Although your service is expecting `id` and `order`, but you're passing `ReachTime` and `Destination` - is this correct?

Comment: yes,  data: "ReachTime=21-Nov-11&Destination=location", this is not a JSON string

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you are getting? See tool such as Fiddler (or Firebug on Firefox) to inspect the request/response - see the response for your ajax request - that will help you to troubleshoot the issue.

OTH, you need a [ScriptService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) attribute applied to your web service class. If you are using .NET 2.0/3.5 then you also need configuration entries to register `ScriptHandlerFactory` handler that is responsible for JSON support in asmx services. See this article for more info regarding configuration: http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/

Comment: @nmathur, is there any request (as seen in fiddler)? If yes, there has to be HTTP response from server (unless the request is timed out which is unlikely). If you are using fiddler on localhost then use `localhost.` (notice period at the end) so that request/response are captured in the tool.

Comment: control is not going to my webservice (i have put a breakpoint there) ... i don't know what is the issue

Comment: @nmathur, that's can be because ASP.NET run-time could not decipher the request. Why are you not using Fiddler (or Firebug) as advised?

Comment: actullay i am a beginner and don't have knowledge about all these things. I am searching about fiddler on Google and after trying that i will tell you about the results. Thanks for you advise :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help ... a combination of your help worked for me .. here is the solution:

```
   $(function () {
       $.ajax({

           type: "POST",
           url: "WebService.asmx/InsertRediretTime",
           data: '{ ReachTime: "21-Nov-11", Destination: "location" }',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: JSON,
           success: function (data, status) {
               alert(data.d);
           }

       });
   });
```

and,

```
  public void InsertRediretTime(string ReachTime, string Destination)
  {
      blah blah
  }
```

Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this,    
in aspx page 
    $(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "WebService.asmx/InsertRediretTime",
               data: '{ReachTime:21-Nov-11,Destination:location}',
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data, status) {
                   alert(data.d);
               }
           });
       });


    In webservice

    public string InsertRediretTime(string ReachTime, string Destination)
    {
    //operational code
     return stringData;
    }
```